# Why do states postpone their primary elections to after June 9th, 2020 even if it violates DNC rules?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, primaries, democratic-party, democratic-primary

The Democratic National Committee (DNC) mandates that states have to hold their primary elections before June 9th, 2020, according to [Rule 12 of the Delegate Selection Rules](https://democrats.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2020-Delegate-Selection-Rules-12.17.18-FINAL.pdf).

> The Delegate Selection Rules provide that each state’s first determining step must take place by 9 June. If a state violates the rule on timing, or any other rule, they could be subject to penalties as prescribed in Rule 21, including at least a 50% reduction in delegates, which will need to be reviewed by the RBC.
>
> Source: [*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/mar/17/dnc-memo-primary-delays-could-result-delegate-reduction)

However, Louisiana and Kentucky [both rescheduled their primaries](https://www.nytimes.com/article/2020-campaign-primary-calendar-coronavirus.html) to be held after June 9th, specifically on June 20th and June 23rd respectively. Kentucky rescheduled their primary to June 23rd even after DNC earlier warned Louisiana on its primary reschedule that "changing the primary to June 20th violates the committee's 'rule on timing'".

So, are there any practical reasons why must these states hold their primaries after June 9th, especially since it is viable to hold them before June 9th, given that a large number of primaries are currently scheduled for June 2nd.

Comment: As a purely practical reason, it would give the states time to organize a purely mail-in ballot.  (And note that some states also have other matters on the same ballot, e.g. my state used to hold city government elections on the same day as the primary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious reason to postpone (and why it is allowed to break the rules) is the current Corona crisis. Although it is estimated to be handled before May is over there is no certainty of it. So this definitely falls under a form of special circumstances (Entire countries are currently on lock down).

So it is better to plan ahead in a what more distant future,This is for several reasons:

- **Financial:** seeing in both logistics and cost it get's more expensive
  to reschedule the closer you are to the date of when you hold it.
- **Health:** Everybody be it a democrat or a republican wants this corona
  madness to be over, so no large events not even important ones like
  this in the hopes the spread will be reduced enough for the virus to
  die out.
- **Politics:** The Democratic party often sell themselves as the
  levelheaded and repsonsible party, if they are going to take such a
  huge risk with the public health they might lose a lot of support.

Comment: Biggest reason to not care is the DNC does not determine state or federal law. If the DNC chooses to screw with their own delegations and piss their own members they are welcome to do so but that has no effect on law.